# Why is my Redirect not working after the verifications?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

This following code is trying to verify something then need to redirect to homepage.

```js
const EmailLink = () => {
    
  const testEmailAuth = () => {
    if (firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(window.location.href)) {
      if (!email) {
        return null;
      }
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailLink(email, window.location.href)
        .then(function(result) {
          window.location.href = '/';
          // <Redirect to="/"/>
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('error ' + error);
        });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="EmailLink">
      {testEmailAuth()}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am trying to redirect with `Redirect` from `react-router-dom`.
Its not working.

Its is working with `window.location.href = '/'`.
Can I know why? & how to make things works with redirect

```
<Switch>
          <Route path="/finishedSignUp" component={EmailLink}/>
  </Switch>

export default withRouter(RootComponent);
```

Comment: This isn't how JSX is returned/rendered. Can you post your full component code? Is the component being rendered within a `Router`?

Comment: And is `EmailLink` rendered within a `Router` in your application?

Comment: Email Link is between the `<Switch>` statement & is exporting with `withRouter`
using `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `EmailLink` is rendered in `Switch` by a `Route` component it receives [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props). Use the passed `history` object to handle the redirect using `history.replace()`.

Side note, you should not issue asynchronous calls and side effects from the "render", use an `useEffect` hook to handle this when the component mounts.

```
const EmailLink = ({ history, match }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const testEmailAuth = () => {
      if (firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(match.url)) {
        if (!email) {
          return null;
        }
        firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithEmailLink(email, match.url)
          .then(function(result) {
            history.replace('/'); // <-- replace === redirect
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('error ' + error);
          });
      }
    };

    testEmailAuth();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="EmailLink" />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is not located inside Router provider for `<Redirect to="/" />` to work.

If you cannot put this code inside filed that is wrapped with Router provider you can make instance for router and use it anywhere in your application:

Also you need to provide your router provider with this instance of browser history

**App.jsx**

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

const App = () => {
  return <Router history={browserHistory}>...</Router>;
};
```

Later on you can use it in your code:

```js
import { browserHistory } from 'App';

firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithEmailLink(email, window.location.href)
  .then(function (result) {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('emailForSignIn');
    browserHistory.push('/');
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error ' + error);
  });
```

You also need to provide this instance of `browserHistory` inside your router:

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) says:

> Rendering a  will navigate to a new location. The new
> location will override the current location in the history stack, like
> server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(null);

  const someFunction = () => {
    //Set redirect to display Redirect and go to /
    setRedirect("/");
  };

  return redirect ? (
    <Redirect to={redirect} />
  ) : (
    <div>{/** rest of your app */}</div>
  );
}
```